# My health is deteriorating. Should I continue taking fasts?

Tags: scripture, sin, fasting

I've been taking fasts (Mondays, Tuesdays, Ekadashis, and Trayodashis) for the last two years. Before, I was able to fast continuously even for five days. I was also able to take many nirjala fasts. But recently, my health has been deteriorating and I'm not able to fast like before. Will it be okay if I stop fasting due to my deteriorating health? I'll be continuing my bhakti and devotion. But my deteriorating health is causing me problems during fasting. So, will lord understand if I stop fasting due to health reasons? Or would it be a sin to do so?

Comment: ayurveda specifically says 'eat for 14 days, fast for 1 day' - on ekadashi. krishna in gita says 'one who eats too much, or too little, both are not fit for yoga'. nobody said u have to fast for 5 days. but then again, if u r doing it with bhakti, no shastra can stop you. anyways, u can listen to your conscience on these matters.

Comment: God will understand your Bhakti, infact He accepts anything with Bhakti, So don't worry Take Care, God is soo compassionate, sooo much compassionate he will understand everything